# inject url into background-image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
@media #{$only-small} {

    .beverages--element .inner:before{
        background-image: url(....);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
```

I have this piece of code, it is used to style a box where a show a beverage in a list of beverages.

so far so good, up until now I've always used the same image for all the beverages. now I need to extend the logic, each beverage now has a different image. the image is stored in a cloud service and I have it's link the in the database where the beverages are stored. how can I pass the link from the view to the css?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to set the background image inline, in the html. Like so:

```
<div style="background-image:(...)">mydiv</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that this is a before-item. I haven't worked on the styling myself I would like to use what has been provided to me.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is recommended to use asset pipeline, you can do the following approach for smaller code. 
You should use `.css.erb` extension for your css and let the runtime evaluate the code in CSS.

```
@media #{$only-small} {

    .beverages--element .inner:before{
        background-image: <%= @beverage_url_image %>;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
```

where `@beverage_1_url_image` should have the URL from your view.

Comment: but in the same page I have different beverages

Comment: then you can do only with @Emir's solution